# Increase max java heap size via pom file

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a `java` application which needs to parse big text files (more than 500 mB). And I would like to increase max heap size for program launch.

If it is possible to set max heap size in `maven` pom file, so that I do not need to pass "-Xmx512m" argument via command line each time?

I looked through some existing articles, but they suggest to change Environment Variables or configure surefire plugin for unit test run. However this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: how do you start your application? Since the pom file is only there during the build it would be a strange place to put it. I would guess you create some sort of batch file to start your application? If so in there would be a good place to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The Maven POM file dictates how your artefact is built (a jar file in your case I suppose), not how you configure your JVM to run the application afterwards.

You typically create a shell script (.bat for Windows and .sh for the rest) to run your Java application

Answer (score 0):

The Maven POM is designated for producing the JAR file itself. There is no way to influence the manner how it is started in a JVM afterwards.

You could, however, use another project for [assembling](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) a ready-to-rollout software. We usually assemble a project to a ZIP file that contains several JAR files as well as a script for launching the application. This script could contain the usual command

```
java -Xmx512m ...
```